# GPIB ibconfig command

Tags: gpib

Very ancient device (from 80th). ibcmd works fine but ibwrt is not working. The device just ignore it. Don't response. May be I should call ibconfig and change the setup somehow? Any help'd be appreciated.

Comment: Can you give more information about the instrument and controller? Which GPIB interface are you using to send the commands? From the documentation, `ibcmd` is used to set up the GPIB interface, `ibwrt` is used to communicate with the instrument. It sounds like your interface isn't set correctly yet. https://documentation.help/NI-488.2/IBCMD.html

Comment: The device was made as a single sample and only I have it. So there's no any info about it else where. But in docs it says it supports GPIB. I use NI usb-gpib cable and NI interface to send commands.

Comment: I don't know if we'll be able to help you much if the tool is one-of-a-kind. But your error tells me that the NI interface is working, but you are not connected to the device yet. Try the documentation here to try and configure your system correctly: https://www.ni.com/en/support/documentation/supplemental/06/configuring-your-gpib-driver-to-match-your-system.html